# How to use a custom WinRT library in a Win32 desktop app?

Tags: dll, windows-8, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I have a WinRT class (C++/CX ref class) in my Win32-based desktop app. It accesses WinRT APIs and works just fine. I used [this guide](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-winrt-apis-from-desktop-applications) to get it working. Now I'm trying to put this class in a library that the desktop app can use. I'm having quite a bit of trouble with this. Here's what I did in Visual Studio 2013:

1. Created a new project by selecting *Installed > Templates> Visual C++ > Store Apps > Windows Apps > DLL (Windows)*.
2. Added this new DLL project to the solution containing my desktop app.
3. Added a reference to the DLL project
4. In *Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional #using Directories* I added the directory where the .winmd file gets built by the DLL project.
5. In a .cpp file in the desktop app, I added:

```c++
#using <MyLib.winmd>
#using <Windows.winmd>
#using <Platform.winmd>

[MTAThread] // initializes WinRT runtime
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow) {
    MyWinRTClass^ myObject = ref new MyWinRTClass();
}
```

Intellisense works and I wrote code to instantiate the class from the library. The desktop app builds, but when it runs I get:

> First-chance exception at 0x76494598 in MyDesktopApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Platform::ClassNotRegisteredException ^ at memory location 0x00A8F99C.

What's going on? Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update as of 7/26/2019: Please see comments from "Adam Braden - MSFT" in the below thread.

This is not possible.  In order for an app to use a custom WinRT component, the component needs to be "registered" first.  For packaged (AppX) apps this is done by adding some information into the AppXManifest.xml of the package.  However for regular Win32 Desktop apps, there is now way for such registration.  You can call WinRT API directly provided by the OS but you cannot write to your own custom WinRT API to be consumed by other apps.

Comment: Could this be achieved by writing manifest files for [Registration-Free COM activation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx#rfacomwalk_topic6)? I am in need of the same "feature" for doing some batch-processing using a winrt library...

Comment: @yms were you successful?

Comment: @ kayleeFrye_onDeck  not really, the best I could do was to create an app for the specific purpose of testing the library, then communicate with it using some kind of IPC.

Comment: (1) As of the Fall Creators Update (1709) version 16299, the Desktop Bridge supports calling 3rd party WinRT components. Use the Windows Application Packaging Project to package the app. More info here https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/07/06/calling-winrt-components-win32-process-via-desktop-bridge and here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net

Comment: Also (2) as of the May 2019 update (1903) version 18362, you can use Registration Free WinRT if you cannot package your app, see https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/04/30/enhancing-non-packaged-desktop-apps-using-windows-runtime-components/